# Is webBrowser Activex installed with IE or should I need to download it

Tags: internet-explorer, installation, webbrowser-control, activex

I'm using the webBrowser ActiveX in an application and need to be sure my users will have this control installed. Is this a separate installation from IExplorer?
In the past I've used ocx control but I don't know which file and where to look on my machine (Windows7 64) and if there are 32 and 64 bits versions?

Comment: It's a part of Windows OS, both 32bit and 64bit.

Comment: Would you have any "Official links" to dumentaion about this? Regards

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741313(v=vs.85).aspx